# Anim Plot Updating

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to find maximum values of a sinusoidal and show it in a subplot. And trying to update it like an animation. But the subplot of the maximum values gives all zero values. When I print the array it is not zeroes. I think it is not updating y values.  I couldn't figure out the reason. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

I will put my code it is executable:

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()
fs = 1e6
Ts = 1/fs
SNR=10
sinfreq=2*pi*1e5
pack= 512
t = Ts*arange(0,pack)
f = fs*(arange(0,pack)-pack/2)/pack
max_y = zeros (len(t))
y=sin(sinfreq*t)        
y=y+randn(size(y))/sqrt(10^(SNR/10)*2) 
subplot(211)       
line1, = plot(y)

subplot(212)
line2, = plot(max_y)
for i1 in arange(1,1000):  
    y=sin(sinfreq*t)
    y=y+randn(size(y))/sqrt(10^(SNR/10)*2)

    line1.set_ydata(y)  

    mk=0
    for mk in range(0,len(y)):
        if y[mk] > max_y[mk]:
            max_y[mk] = y[mk]
    print max_y
    line2.set_ydata(max_y) 
    draw()                        
    waitforbuttonpress(timeout=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution incidentally, I don't know the reason but I update my max_y plot any other value firstly then do my real update, then the plot shows my changes. Other than this it is not showing. I try with different for loops they are ploting with one update but for my loop it wanted to update twice.

I have also add set_ylim to see better the limits. I put stars to places that I have changed. I am putting the new code also. I wish it will help people that have the same problem.

```
from pylab import *
import time

ion()
fs = 1e6
Ts = 1/fs
SNR=10
sinfreq=2*pi*1e5
pack= 512
t = Ts*arange(0,pack)
f = fs*(arange(0,pack)-pack/2)/pack
max_y = zeros (len(t))
y=sin(sinfreq*t)        
y=y+randn(size(y))/sqrt(10^(SNR/10)*2) 
subplot(211)      
line1, = plot(y)

sub2=subplot(212) #****
line2, = plot(max_y)
for i1 in arange(1,1000):  
    y=sin(sinfreq*t)
    y=y+randn(size(y))/sqrt(10^(SNR/10)*2)

    line1.set_ydata(y)  

    mk=0
    for mk in range(0,len(y)):
        if y[mk] > max_y[mk]:
            max_y[mk] = y[mk]
    #print max_y
    line2.set_ydata(zeros(len(max_y)))#****     
    line2.set_ydata(max_y) 
    sub2.set_ylim(min(max_y),max(max_y)) #****
    draw()                        
    waitforbuttonpress(timeout=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten an indent in the second for loop. 
That should actually give you an IndentationError, so I don't understand how you can say that the program is executable (in fact, I edited your entry to remove the left-over "enter code here" statement; if you had checked and copy-pasted your entry, you'd probably found both mistakes).

But, are you sure you don't want simply

```
max_y[:] = max(y)
```

instead of that for loop?

Comment: OK, sorry for that indentation Error. I saw the other thing but i didnt see the edit part as long as this was my first question. Now i have changed, and corrected. I said it is executable because i execute it before putting here. Sorry I must have done something and change the indentation. But the code you are saying is not doing the same thing with mine. Now you are doing all the maximum values are the same, but i was doing samplewise comparison, and finding maximum for each place. Are you sure they are the same?

Comment: But my question is still the same. Whey second subplot is not updating?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the subplot *is* being updated. However, the plot is almost always the same (I can see it being updated because of tiny changes, probably due to resolution and rounding). Look at the max_y values you're printing (better, just look at the first 5 or 10, to avoid filling up your terminal).
That is why I asked if you wanted the loop; try replacing the loop with the `max_y[:] = max(y) statement` and see if it changes. Note: you either need to adjust the scale on the second plot or divide max_y by 100 in that case; otherwise it draws the line outside the plot.

Comment: Ok i have changed my code as you say after the 14th line as
`a=subplot(211)       
line1, = plot(max_y)
b=subplot(212)
line2, = plot(y)
for i1 in arange(1,1000):  
    y=i1*sin(sinfreq*t)
    y=y+randn(size(y))/sqrt(10^(SNR/10)*2)
    line1.set_ydata(y)  
    mk=0
    max_y[:] = max(y)
    line2.set_ydata(max_y) 
    draw()                        
    waitforbuttonpress(timeout=0.5)
    a.set_ylim(min(y),max(y))
    b.set_ylim(min(max_y),max(max_y))`
but the line stays as its first place. Plot is still not updating. I couldn't understand why.